# Apex:inputfile style

Tags: visualforce, lightning, style

Im trying to give the 'choose file' button the lightning style,I tried to set the header on True,but its not working with that component. Is there any other way to do it?

```
<apex:form id="theForm">

  <apex:pageBlock >

      <apex:pageBlockSection >

        <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" styleClass="slds-file-selector__button"  / >

        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>



   </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: You might have to try lightning:stylesheets https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to import SLDS stylesheets to your visualforce page.

To add SLDS to your page, add the `<apex:slds/>` tag anywhere on your page. The `<apex:slds/>` tag imports SLDS stylesheets so you don’t have to do it yourself.

Also, there is more that needs to be done in order to give `inputFile` a lightning button look.

Below visualforce page should do the trick

```
<apex:page >
   <apex:form id="theForm">
      <apex:slds />
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="file-selector-id">Attachment</span>
               <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                  <div class="slds-file-selector slds-file-selector_files">
                     <div class="slds-file-selector__dropzone">
                        <apex:inputFile styleClass="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" accept="image/png" id="fileUploadInput01" value="foo" />
                        <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-file-selector__body" for="fileUploadInput01">
                           <span class="slds-file-selector__button slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                              <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                                 <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#upload"></use>
                              </svg>
                              Upload Files
                           </span>
                           <span class="slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show">or Drop Files</span>
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can get further help on this topic at [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_lightning_design) link

Comment: Well,  this does answer the question but uses a link which can break / change. Can you add some sample code snippet?

Comment: Yup Thanks @Pranay ! Updated the answer.

Comment: +1. Thanks...  :)

Comment: Have you tried if it works? I don't think this works though.

Comment: @JayantDas it seems you are right.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it seems there's no effect of SLDS on `apex:inputFile`. Seems it has to be a custom styling within the VF only.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Jayant Yes, you were correct, it is not as straight forward as I thought, I updated the code and answer which worked for me.

Comment: Hello agani! do you know how to display the uploaded file name where the slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show is?.

Comment: Hi @Dead_end_Developer, I would recommend you to post a separate question for this. Though a solution can be provided here, but this is the way SFSE works and it is always better to post a separate question so that the wider community can have a look at your requirement and serve you better with different kinds of solutions and perspectives.